# plotBands Highcharts, if i increase pointInterval the data is display with mismatching

Tags: javascript, highcharts

PlotBand Highchart, i use plotbands that's working fine. ex: *9-dec value is 104* if i increase the pointerInterval,value 104 is set into some other date like *17-dec value is 104*, how to solve it.
thanks 
refer [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/584oph2x/6/)

[1](https://jsfiddle.net/584oph2x/6/): https://jsfiddle.net/584oph2x/5/`enter code here`

after change pointerInterval
   refer [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/584oph2x/6/)

Comment: What exactly is wrong here? If you ask for 2 days between points, each value in data will have 2 days between them. If you ask for 1 day between, that is what you get. Seems like the desired behavior...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are increasing the plotInterval to two days  I guess , so the data will be matched with respect to that use this data to match the graph at Dec-9

```
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

JSfiddle Reference https://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/mzft8chv/1/